# SQL Server: DB STARTUP blocking processes

Tags: sql-server-2012, restore, recovery

I am trying to run

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE
```

(or CHECKDB, same result), but I keep getting this error:

> Check statement aborted. Database contains deferred transactions.

I've made some researches and found that it's some process with SPID 5 and command DB STARTUP blocks everything. This process is running for a few days already but neither

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

nor

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(5)
```

show anything. Looks like it just sits there and does nothing.

I've checked the logs for that database and it seems that recovery process went fine (last records are about step 3 of 3 running and that over 500K transactions were rolled back so I assume it's done).

I've tried some advice from Google but none of them helped. Setting database to SINGLE_USER, EMERGENCY and even OFFLINE changed nothing. All of them were blocked in one way or another. I can't restore it from earlier backup for some reasons, and there is no more good advice in Google.

Restarting the SQL Server makes database inaccessible saying something like *"Lock timeout, error 1222"* so I have to recreate virtual machine from an image. I also can't take a backup nor restore from earlier one.

Comment: Can you post snippet from errorlog which says that database has recovered fully and is online.

Comment: here is a screenshot. I'm not 100% sure but it looks like it's recovered, no? http://prntscr.com/dgvkez

Comment: also since it was inaccessible, I've decided to reattach it, but it stuck at this state: http://prntscr.com/dgvlfv nothing changes for hours, just estimated time increases

Comment: NO it is not recovered fully let it recovery, you would see message database is online

Comment: it's still the same 95% despite more than 20h passed. Is there any way to check what exactly it does right now?

Comment: Yep we can [See This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2010/12/29/tracking-database-recovery-progress-using-information-from-dmv/)

Comment: So just to finish it: nothing helperd at all. Fortunately, original production environment database was still accessible, so I've managed to recreate structure at new database and then pulled all the data I was able to get. Thanks for your help.